# Create a bridged interface on separate NIC but same subnet as host gateway

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

*Note: I couldn't find a straight-forward answer in any of the duplicates flagged for this question. The problem is the "right answer" seems to depend very heavily on which release you are running and whether you have a desktop or server profile. I have a bit of both because I installed lubuntu-core to provide some basic remote X functionality and it seems NetworkManager was installed as well but we prefer to edit our network config by hand not use the GUI tools.*

Situation is I have a remote Ubuntu 14.04 server I need to reconfigure networking on. I need to safely add a bridged interface `eth1` to the remote system without breaking remote connectivity. I have a new /etc/network/interfaces file I want to load but because I don't have an equivalent machine to test it on or physical access to the server I have some questions about my new configuration:

1. Is the gateway configuration and metric in the file below valid for what
   I'm trying to do and,
2. Will network manager override or interfere with what I'm doing here? Currently when I `ifup eth1` network manager just brings it
   down automatically. I'm afraid to disable NM in case it kills the
   remote connection, and
3. If I reboot the system with the updated file and my current configuration should it be able to receive a remote SSH connection when it comes back up?

The server has NetworkManager currently running however I don't need it. I only care that the configuration in /etc/network/interfaces is used and that the machine remains accessible for remote SSH login at all stages of reconfiguration (ie, I do not want to get locked out by a misconfiguration or by taking both interfaces down without a script or reboot automatically and correctly bring them back on).

`eth0` is the default interface for host traffic. `eth1` is going to be a bridge for a KVM virtual machine with it's own external IP address. Both interfaces connect to the same physical switch and share the X.X.X.0/24 subnet. My understanding is I need a bridge for this to work BUT I also need to be careful about my gateways and metrics because I have 2 interfaces on the same network.

The host currently has the following NetworkManager status:

```
# nmcli d status
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE
eth1       802-3-ethernet    unavailable
eth0       802-3-ethernet    unmanaged
```

And configuration in NetworkManager.conf:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

I've created the new config below:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address X.X.X.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network X.X.X.0
        broadcast X.X.X.255
        gateway X.X.X.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers X.X.X.2
        dns-search example.com
        # Interfaces with lower values get used first
        metric 10

### NEW BRIDGED INTERFACE ON ETH1 ###
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address X.X.X.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network X.X.X.0
        broadcast X.X.X.255
        # do I need gateway here or will it conflict with eth0 ?
        # gateway X.X.X.1
        metric 20

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address X.X.X.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network X.X.X.0
        broadcast X.X.X.255
        gateway X.X.X.1
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 5
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers X.X.X.2
        dns-search example.com
        metric 30
```

As I said though, with this new config just added to the server an `ifup eth1` only works until NM decides to remove it. That's making testing anything problematic but I'm worried simply disabling NM could be much worse.

Comment: I do not think anyone can guarantee you will not loose connectivity.

Comment: sure, I just meant the process can't assume I'm on a local console and can ifdown/ifup at will. If I lose the interface permanaentely I'm screwed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just replaced the eth1 config with

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
```

... crossed my fingers and ran `reboot`. The system came back up with the eth0 and br0 interfaces correct though the "solution" isn't one I was at all comfortable with and I'm sure a better answer exists.